# JavaScript Regexp replace with grouping Euro symbol's

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Trying create Regexp for `&#8203; € 14,50` after complete replacement must left only

> 14,50

maybe someone can Help ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/xTEi4l/1)

The below regex simply ensures it's not preceded by a `#`

```
[^#\d](\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

Alternatively: `€ *(\d+(?:,\d+)?)`, which ensures it's preceded by `€` followed by any number of spaces.

#### Usage

```js
var r = /[^#\d](\d+(?:,\d+)?)/g;
var s = `&#8203; € 14,50`

console.log(r.exec(s)[1]);
```

**Alternative**

```js
var r = /€ *(\d+(?:,\d+)?)/g;
var s = `&#8203; € 14,50`

console.log(r.exec(s)[1]);
```

---

### Explanation

- `[^#\d]` Match anything not present in the set (anything except `#` and a digit)
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `\d+` Match any digit one or more times
  - `(?:,\d+)?` Match zero or one time the following

    - `,` Match the comma character `,` literally
    - `\d+` Match any digit one or more times